# How to call a servlet on Glassfish server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, servlets, http-post, glassfish-3

I am trying to call a servlet form my android application in eclipse. I have to use the Glassfish application server(the servlet is in a different Mavan project). I had a few questions:

1. How to start a glassfish server in Eclipse?
2. What URL do I pass in the HttpPost() method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is the Servers view in which you can add you GF instance. However, this is not mandatory and you can run it from the command line (asadmin).
2. If your GF runs locally, the URL will start with 
   http :// localhost/webappName/servletPath

localhost or 127.0.0.1

I'd advise you to get a training as the more you'll progress, the more questions you'll have.